# Drop down options enabled based on the user

Tags: google-docs

Okay, this might seem stupid since it's my first time using Google Docs, and this could have a very simple solution, but I have not managed to find an answer by googling.

Basically, my sheet has a dropdown with 3 options. The sheet has 3 active users editing it. How would I go about making the option "A" on dropdown only available to user "A", and so on? Basically, letting user "A" pick only the option I allow him to. If such a thing is not possible, what would be the workaround? Once again, I'm sorry for asking something this seemingly simple, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want cannot be achieved since protection for ranges works for a chosen range whereas the data validation options are all in the same range, and not separate ones.

What you can do:

**1. Protect the range for each specific user**

Since each user has only one option available, you can create three cells which would represent the options for each user. Afterwards, you will have to protect each of them in order to let only the wanted user access the wanted cell/option.

**2. Make use of Apps Script**

Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

Even though this still won't allow you to achieve the task directly, you can ask the user to input their email address and based on the response, display the customized content:

```
function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var result = ui.prompt('Please enter your email address:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
   var button = result.getSelectedButton();
   var text = result.getResponseText();

   if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
      ui.alert('I didn\'t get your name.');
   } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
   }
   if (text == 'user_a@email.com')
     // display the content for user A
   else if (text == 'user_b@email.com')
     //display the content for user B
  else if (text == 'user_c@email.com')
     //display the content for user C
}
```

#### Reference

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en);
- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [Promp Dialogs Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs).